# Unable to bind tkinter slider properly to functions

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a naive city generator. I have been successful at making the blocks of specified heights.

Also, I have been able to write a script that changes the height of a block using the slider.

**Problem**

1. I am not able to do both things together. (I think I can solve this because the error is only about referencing before assignment)
2. Using a horizontal slider, I want to increase the number of buildings (visualize as increasing the number of bars on the x-axis by reducing the width). But this code just does not work, I mean, it is not even raising errors.

**Code so far**

```
from tkinter import *
import random

bars = 5
margin = 30
heights= [5, 2, 1, 8, 4]
blocks = []
length = 600
breadth = 360

def draw():
    aligner = margin
    width = (breadth - margin*2)/bars
    for height in heights :
        block = {"height" : height }
        block['rect'] = canvas.create_rectangle(aligner,550-50*height,aligner+width,550, fill="green")
        block['color'] = 'green'
        blocks.append(block)
        aligner += width
    root.update()


def wid(e):
    bars = int(e)
    blocks = []
    heights = []
    for i in range(bars):
        h = random.random()*10
        heights.append(h)
    draw()

def h_rand(e):
    factor = e
    heights = [i * factor for i in heights]
    draw()

root = Tk()


width = 60
aligner = 30

slider_y = Scale(root, from_=1 , to=8, bg="blue",command = h_rand)
slider_y.pack(side=LEFT)

canvas = Canvas(root,height=length,width=breadth)
canvas.pack()

for height in heights :
    block = {"height" : height }
    block['rect'] = canvas.create_rectangle(aligner,550-50*height,aligner+width,550, fill="green")
    block['color'] = 'green'
    blocks.append(block)
    aligner += width


slider_x = Scale(root, from_=50 , to=200, orient = HORIZONTAL, bg="blue",command = wid)
slider_x.pack(side=TOP)

root.mainloop()
```

I am sorry for the "not so descriptive formatting" of the question (*happy to give further details in the comments*). It is bothering me for a while now and I am just frustrated.

Comment: Hmmmm,you set a variable `width` and a function also called `width`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I  don't suppose that should raise any errors as command always takes a function as an attribute and not a variable. Anyway, I did change it, but, still no luck!

Comment: Due to I really don't know what you want to do,You can change the `draw()` function to `draw(bars)`.And change `draw()` to ``draw(bars)`` in your function `wid(e)`.It will take some changes when you drag the slider.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA it has started scaling down the previous bars but doesn't add new ones, but thanks for helping me ahead. Do tell if u have a solution for that as well

Comment: You can try to debug your code.Because your code is a little.....difficult to read.You set a list `heights`,but in your function `h_rand(e)`,you also used `heights = [i * factor for i in heights]`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Done. I just only had to pass in the heights as well with the bars in the function, but I don't understand, if I am specifying it as a global parameter(which I did before you edited my post), shouldn't every reference of heights refer to the same list?

Comment: emmm,I edited your post because you posted the repeat code(You can see it in the Timeline).If you don't specify it as a global parameter,it can be referred in function,but can not be revised if it is a variable that can't be change(such as number or string).You can try it by test.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA (I know its a bad practice to write this but this one is from the heart) Thanx bro, you have helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `heights` in `wid` is a local variable. You're changing the value inside the function, but the global variable is left unchanged.

You either need to declare `heights` as global inside the function, or use the global variable without replacing it with a new list.

To declear it as global, add `global heights` at the top of the function where it's being modified:

```
def wid(e):
    global heights, blocks
    ...
```

You can use the `clear` method of a list to remove the contents without resetting the variable itself. To do that, replace `heights = []` with `heights.clear()` and the same for `blocks`:

```
def wid(e):
    bars = int(e)
    print("bars:", bars)
    blocks.clear()
    heights.clear()
    ...
```

---

You also have the problem that you're not deleting the old canvas items before creating the new. Your `draw` function needs to destroy the old elements. You can do that with `canvas.delete("all")`.

Comment: I was having problems implementing this using global variables, now I know why. Got around it by reformatting the whole code into classes and referencing the attributes as a particular instance of that class. (This way now issue of polymorphism). I also recognized the error regarding the canvas.delete(). Still thanks!....... I have no experience in what to do when I have solved the problem I have posted, could you guide me?